# Display random post for 24h as home page Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, random, plugins

I'm looking for a way to display the content of my random post as a main page. This post should be displayed for 24h. Meaning: on Monday my home page shows post1, on Tuesday, when one enters my home page again, it displays post2, etc.

Posts are picked randomly from my posts list...

I've spent couple of hours already looking for the right plugin... no luck so far :/

Answer (score -1):

```
$randomPosts = get_posts(array(
   'orderby' => 'rand',
   'posts_per_page' => 1,
   'tag' => $tag,
));
```

Comment: the OP requested a new post every 24hrs. Your answer does not reflect that.